# How to turn off code completion in Firebug 1.6?

Tags: firebug

How can I turn off the really annoying code completion in the firebug 1.6 command line?

UPDATE: it turned out that John's approach below just hides the completion popup, but doesn't disable autocompletion itself in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

see: http://blog.getfirebug.com/category/firebug-releases/page/2/

Firebug 1.6a20
Wednesday, August 18th, 2010

getfirebug.com has Firebug 1.6a20.  All tests pass on Firefox 3.6.9. We plan 1.6b1 for early next week in conjunction with Firefox 4.0b4 which looks like it will work for everything except AJAX debugging.

**This release includes a preference you can set via about:config to disable the popup completion dialog**, extensions.firebug.commandLineShowCompleterPopup. We will disable the popup on Linux by default for Firefox 3.6.The Mozilla platform feature we use (panel) does not work correctly on Linux. We will evaluate it on Firefox 4.0. We may add a user interface control for this option if it seems like the completion works well enough without the popup.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me... just wonder why they didn't include an on/off switch for this directly into firebug. Since code completion is a very experimental feature, I expected a more obvious way to disable it.